# Longtable format question

Tags: longtable

I am using the longtable environment.  When the table renders, there is an open space between the header row and the body rows, but not between the leading column and the body columns.  How can I get both of these spaces open?  (Both closed is also interesting but I prefer open.)

[image]

```
\begin{longtable}{| c || c | c | c | c |  }
                \hline
                  +& 0 & $~y\in\mathbb{R}_0~$ & $~\big(\aleph_\mathcal{Y}+ a\big)\in\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $ & $~\big(\widehat\infty- |a|\big)\in\mathbb{R}_0^1\cup\widehat\infty~   $  \\ [4pt]
                \hline\hline
                 $0 \vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $&0& $y$  &$\aleph_\mathcal{Y}+ a$ & $\widehat\infty- |a|$ \\ [4pt]
                \hline
                 $~x~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $ & $x$ & $x+y$ &$\aleph_\mathcal{Y}+ \big(a+ x\big)$ &$\widehat\infty- \big(|a|- x\big)$ \\[4pt]
                \hline
                 $~\big(\aleph_\mathcal{X}+ b\big)~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $  & $\aleph_\mathcal{X}+ b$ & $\aleph_\mathcal{X}+ \big(b+y\big)$ &$\aleph_{(\mathcal{X+Y})}+ \big(b+a\big)$ &$\aleph_{(\mathcal{X}+1)}+ \big(b-|a|\big)$\\[4pt]
                \hline
                  $~\big(\widehat\infty- |b|\big)~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}}   $   & $\widehat\infty- |b|$ &   $\widehat\infty- \big(|b|-y\big)$ &$\aleph_{(1+\mathcal{ Y})}- \big(|b|-a\big)$  &$\aleph_{2}- \big(|b|+|a|\big)$\\[4pt]
                \hline
            \end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can read the doc of `tabularray` to learn how to set caption or other.

## Open

If you want open, you need to calculate the `leftpos` and `rightpos`, you can read [rounding error (?) when doing double or triple line borders in table · Issue #216 · lvjr/tabularray](https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/216). If you set the sep between two rule is `1.2pt`, the default rule width is `0.4pt`, the pos is equal to `0.4/(0.4*2+1.2)=0.2`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}
[
label=none,
]
{
colspec={Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
rulesep=1.2pt,
hline{2}={1}{1}{rightpos=.2},
hline{2}={2}{1}{rightpos=.2},
hline{2}={1}{2-Z}{leftpos=.2},
hline{2}={2}{2-Z}{leftpos=.2},
hline{1,3-Z}={1}{rightpos=.2},
hline{1,3-Z}={2-Z}{leftpos=.2},
vline{1,3-Z}={belowpos=0},
vline{2}={1}{-}{belowpos=0},
vline{2}={2}{-}{belowpos=0},
}
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Close

If you want to close, it is more simple.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}
[
label=none,
]
{
colspec={Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
rulesep=1.2pt,
hline{1,3-Z}={},
hline{2}={1}{-}{},
hline{2}={2}{-}{},
vline{1,3-Z}={belowpos=1},
vline{2}={1}{-}{belowpos=1},
vline{2}={2}{-}{belowpos=1},
}
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
test & test & test & test & test \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Do you have any thoughts on getting them both open?  I think that will look a good bit better.

Comment: @hodopsmith I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

By ude of the `hhline` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{| c || c | c | c | c |  }
    \hhline{|-||----|}  % <----
      +& 0 & $~y\in\mathbb{R}_0~$ & $~\big(\aleph_\mathcal{Y}+ a\big)\in\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $ & $~\big(\widehat\infty- |a|\big)\in\mathbb{R}_0^1\cup\widehat\infty~   $  \\ [4pt]
    \hhline{:=::====:}  % <----
     $0 \vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $&0& $y$  &$\aleph_\mathcal{Y}+ a$ & $\widehat\infty- |a|$ \\ [4pt]
    \hline
     $~x~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $ & $x$ & $x+y$ &$\aleph_\mathcal{Y}+ \big(a+ x\big)$ &$\widehat\infty- \big(|a|- x\big)$ \\[4pt]
    \hline
     $~\big(\aleph_\mathcal{X}+ b\big)~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}} $  & $\aleph_\mathcal{X}+ b$ & $\aleph_\mathcal{X}+ \big(b+y\big)$ &$\aleph_{(\mathcal{X+Y})}+ \big(b+a\big)$ &$\aleph_{(\mathcal{X}+1)}+ \big(b-|a|\big)$\\[4pt]
    \hline
      $~\big(\widehat\infty- |b|\big)~\vphantom{\widehat{\overline{\mathbb{R}_0^\mathcal{X}}}}   $   & $\widehat\infty- |b|$ &   $\widehat\infty- \big(|b|-y\big)$ &$\aleph_{(1+\mathcal{ Y})}- \big(|b|-a\big)$  &$\aleph_{2}- \big(|b|+|a|\big)$\\[4pt]
    \hhline{|-||----|}  % <----
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If `hhline` can cut the bottom rules between column 1 and 2?

Comment: @Clara it can (just replace hline by the hhline used on the last line)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to encourage you to pursue a different route toward formatting happiness: Instead of spending time on fixing the appearance of the intersections of double vertical and horizonta lines, I'd like to encourage you to (a) get rid of all vertical lines (trust me, they won't be missed) and (b) use fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines.

Under this alternative, the multitude of `\vphantom` and `[4ex]` spacing adjuster are also no longer needed. And the reduction in code complexity might be welcome as well, right?

As shown in the following screenshot, whitespace can be every bit as effective at forming a visual barrier as a straight (vertical or horizontal) line. Who knows, the absence of visual clutter may even *invite* some of your readers to pause and spend time looking at the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,longtable,array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}} % automatic math mode
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert

\begin{document} 

\begin{longtable}{@{} CCCCC @{}} % all cells are in math mode by default

\toprule
  + 
& 0 
& y\in\mathbb{R}_0 
& (\aleph_{\mathcal{Y}} + a)\in\mathbb{R}_0^{\mathcal{X}}  
& ({\widehat\infty} - \abs{a})\in\mathbb{R}_0^1\cup{\widehat\infty} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot


  0  
& 0
& y  
& \aleph_{\mathcal{Y}} + a 
& {\widehat\infty} - \abs{a} \\ 
\addlinespace

  x  
& x 
& x + y 
& \aleph_{\mathcal{Y}} + (a + x) 
& {\widehat\infty} - (\abs{a} - x) \\
\addlinespace

  (\aleph_{\mathcal{X}} + b)   
& \aleph_{\mathcal{X}} + b 
& \aleph_{\mathcal{X}} + (b + y) 
& \aleph_{(\mathcal{X + Y})} + (b + a) 
& \aleph_{(\mathcal{X} + 1)} + (b - \abs{a}) \\
\addlinespace

  ({\widehat\infty} - \abs{b})      
& {\widehat\infty} - \abs{b} 
& {\widehat\infty} - (\abs{b} - y) 
& \aleph_{(1 + \mathcal{ Y})} - (\abs{b} - a)  
& \aleph_{2} - (\abs{b} + \abs{a}) \\

\end{longtable}   

\end{document}
```